# Problems setting up burp suite

Tags: burp, security-testing

I have problems setting up burp suite on my macbook with google chrome. I have followed all guidelines on the official website and my settings look like this:

[image: pic]

But when I visit websites, I don't see any requests/responses in the intercept tab under Proxy in the program. Why not?

Comment: Did you add the burpsuite certificate as a trusted authority?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Intercept it turned off. Do you see anything in HTTP history?

If not, try setting up a scope in Target > Scope. Also, look at the option, Proxy > Options > Miscellaneous > Don't send items to Proxy history or other Burp tools, if out of scope.

One other possibility: is a Chrome extension managing your proxy settings? There are various extensions that do this, like Foxy Proxy.

Comment: I have checked so that Intercept is on and I don't see anything in the HTTP history. If I add a scope, I don't get anything either, just one thing changes and it says "History logging of out-of-scope items is disabled". I have also checked the "Don't send items to Proxy history or other Burp tools, if out of scope." option and it is checked. I only have editthiscookie and adblock in Chrome addons.

Comment: @user2597001 - Ok, you need to either uncheck that option, or add the site you are testing to the scope (in Target > Scope)

Comment: Okay I tried that with a website, but it still didn't work. I also tried unchecking that option ,still nothing shows up in the HTTP history. So weird. What can be wrong?

Comment: @user2597001 - Try closing Burp, then accessing a web site. Does your browser generate an error like "proxy not responding" ?

Comment: No, I have closed it several times and then I can just visit websites and it works. It feels like something is wrong when you should configure the settings because I always need to change back to port 8081 when I start BurpSuite. By the way, I changed to port 8081 because when I had 8080, I couldn't tick the "Running" checkbox in options in Proxy. Maybe I configured it wrong on port 8080? But followed the guide and read it through many times.

Comment: @user2597001 - If you can't start it on 8080, you have some other service using that port on your computer. You are correct to use port 8081 as you have done. If you can browse when Burp is closed, that means your browser is not configured to use Burp. Try disabling all Chrome extensions. Try a different browser. Firefox has built-in proxy settings; it doesn't use the system settings.